# How can include library to my JAR and move property file to outside this JAR?(MAVEN)

Tags: java, maven, jar, properties

I have some simple java core priject.

I parse file and insert to DB.

My project consist from:

1. One class(Main)
   2.ojdbc7.jar library
2. propery file

I want create JAR file (Main+ ojdbc7.jar library) and move property file outside this JAR.

Now I create this

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>kg.nurtelecom.Flea</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have one JAR with library and property. But I can not edit proberty because it be inside JAR.

How can I include ojdbc7.jar to my MAIN.JAR and move property to outside this JAR?

Comment: is this standalone application?

Answer (score -1):

what you want is something you could do it easily with Spring-Boot.

Here is an example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Basically you will have your pom where you can add as many jars as you need, and a properties files (application.properties) when you build your project you will get a jar file.

Main requirements:

- Java 8
- Maven 3